# DropDown Button in kivy closes immediately

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown

I'm trying to implement a dropdown button in kivy but it closes immediately , I have seen other examples but i can't manage to understand them , any suggestions ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '50sp'
        Button:
            id: button
            text: 'Open dropdown'
    Widget:

    DropDown:
        id: dropdown
        on_parent: self.dismiss()

        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            text: 'item 1'
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            text: 'item 2'
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            text: 'item 3'
'''


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        self.root.ids.button.bind(on_release=self.root.ids.dropdown.open)
        return self.root


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Either disable the action `on_parent: self.dismiss()` or add it to `widget`'s method.

Comment: When i disable it or add it to widget the first button item shows up even before clicking the button.